# Context menu with Konva.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I have a map with multiple objects, like players, towers, enemies etc..

They are added to the map with this function:

```
const createCustomObject = (sides, radius, color, x, y) => {
  let customObject = new Konva.RegularPolygon({
    fill: color,
    x: x,
    y: y,
    sides: sides,
    radius: radius,
    id: returnID()
  });
  customObject.on("click", e => console.log(e.target.id()));
  addLayer(objectLayer, customObject);
};
```

Now i need to change it so that when user clicks on any `customObject`, context menu should appear with clickable options like "Delete", "Show ID" etc..

How exactly can i do that? I was thinking about creating a `Konva.Rect()` onclick and filling with clickable `Konva.Text()` objects, but maybe i'm missing some other way? My one seems to be quite ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that's what i did. I made a rectange, and placed Konva.Text's above it. Then just made onclick function for all Konva.Text elements

Comment: Hi @Skypho. Any possibility of you adding an example to what you did to your answer?

Comment: @Ebbs https://github.com/shakhbulatgaz/dota2-canvas/blob/master/src/scripts/scripts.js

Check out the line 121. There has to be better way, but i gave up back then

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting! I also started working on my own version yesterday. Some of it looks very familiar to what you did. It is far from done and I still need some help getting there. I made an SO post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541783/how-to-create-a-konva-react-context-menu. It has a Sandbox in it if you want to play around.