# How to create a Konva-React context menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contextmenu, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

To the best of my knowledge there isn't an easy/built in way with Konva to create a context menu for right clicking on objects. I am busy working on a project which requires the use of context menus, so I thought I'd just create my own.

Needless to say I am fairly new to Konva, so I was hoping someone on SO might have more experience to help me get over the last hurdles.

I have create a sandbox, located [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/my0k7m54rx)

The requirements are:

1. An object should be draggable. (I copied a working example off the Konva sandbox.)
2. An object should show a context menu when right clicked upon.
3. The context menu should be dynamic, thus allow for multiple items, each executing its own callback when clicked upon.
4. Once a selection has been made, the context menu should be closed.

Thus far I have gotten most of it right, but the things I am struggling with are:

1. I cannot figure out how to hover over one context menu item, have it highlighted, then move to the next which should be highlighted and the old one restored to original settings.
2. Moving out of the context menu repaints the whole object. I don't understand why.
3. Clicking on one items fires both item's callbacks. Why? I a targeting the specific menu item which was clicked on, but getting both?
4. This point is less of a bug and more that I am unsure as how to proceed: How would I prevent multiple context menus to be create if a user right clicks multiple times on the object? Conceptually I understand that I could search for any items in a layer(?) with the name of the context menu and close it, however I have no idea how to do this.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting project - will hit a number of useful techniques. If you do not get any ready-to-eat solutions then you may want to break this down to a number of discreet questions on each topic in your list. Better form for SO to consume.

Comment: Probably it will be better to use an external library for making context menus. That it works via usual DOM, instead of drawing into a canvas. It may be simpler to manage.

Comment: @lavrton I thought about doing that but I am completely unsure as to how as I don't know how to mix canvas with a react component at that level. Problem is the libraries I looked at uses a context provider HOC which should wrap the element, in this case canvas, where the context menu will be used. Then I need to render the context menu on an event. Not sure how that works within canvas. That's why I resorted to drawing my own context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in react but plain JS I am afraid, but it shines a light on some of what you will have to do.

Click the pink circle, then take option 2 and click sub-option 2.

Areas requiring more work:

- deliver the menu config data via JSON
- make adding callbacks a method within the class
- add a timeout on the hide to allow shaky mouse hands
- how to handle hiding sub-menus when user mouse-outs or clicks another option
- add reveal & hide animations

```js
// Set up the canvas / stage
var stage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 600, height: 300});

// Add a layer some sample shapes
var layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
stage.add(layer);

// draw some shapes.
var circle = new Konva.Circle({ x: 80, y: 80, radius: 30, fill: 'Magenta'});
layer.add(circle);

var rect = new Konva.Rect({ x: 80, y: 80, width: 60, height: 40, fill: 'Cyan'});
layer.add(rect);

stage.draw();

// that is the boring bit over - now menu fun

// I decided to set up a plain JS object to define my menu structure - could easily receive from async in JSON format. [Homework #1]
var menuData = { options: [
  {key: 'opt1', text: 'Option 1', callBack: null},
  {key: 'opt2', text: 'Option 2', callBack: null, 
    options: [ 
      {key: 'opt2-1', text: 'Sub 1', callBack: null}, 
      {key: 'opt2-2', text: 'Sub 2', callBack: null} 
   ]
  },
  {key: 'opt3', text: 'Option 3', callBack: null},
  {key: 'opt4', text: 'Option 4', callBack: null}  
]};

// Define a menu 'class' object.
var menu = function(menuData) {

  var optHeight = 20;  // couple of dimension constants. 
  var optWidth = 100;
  var colors = ['white','gold'];
  
  this.options = {}; // prepare an associative list accessible by key - will put key into the shape as the name so we can can get from click event to this entry

  this.menuGroup = new Konva.Group({}); // prepare a canvas group to hold the option rects for this level. Make it accessible externally by this-prefix

  var _this = this;  // put a ref for this-this to overcome this-confusion later. 

  // recursive func to add a menu level and assign its option components.
  var addHost = function(menuData, hostGroup, level, pos){  // params are the data for the level, the parent group, the level counter, and an offset position counter
    var menuHost = new Konva.Group({ visible: false});  // make a canvas group to contain new options
    hostGroup.add(menuHost); // add to the parent group

    // for every option at this level
    for (var i = 0; i < menuData.options.length; i = i + 1 ){
      var option = menuData.options[i]; // get the option into a var for readability

      // Add a rect as the background for the visible option in the menu.
      option.optionRect = new Konva.Rect({x: (level * optWidth), y: (pos + i) * optHeight, width: optWidth, height: optHeight, fill: colors[0], stroke: 'silver', name: option.key });
      option.optionText = new Konva.Text({x: (level * optWidth), y: (pos + i) * optHeight, width: optWidth, height: optHeight, text: ' ' + option.text, listening: false, verticalAlign: 'middle'})
  console.log(option.optionText.height())
      option.optionRect
        .on('mouseover', function(){
          this.fill(colors[1])
          layer.draw();
          })
        .on('mouseleave', function(){
          this.fill(colors[0])
          layer.draw();
          })
      
      // click event listener for the menu option 
      option.optionRect.on('click', function(e){

        var key = this.name(); // get back the key we stashed in the rect so we can get the options object from the lookup list 

        if (_this.options[key] && (typeof _this.options[key].callback == 'function')){ // is we found an option and it has a real function as a callback then call it.
          _this.options[key].callback();
        } 
        else {
          console.log('No callback for ' + key)
        }
        
      })
      menuHost.add(option.optionRect); // better add the rect and text to the canvas or we will not see it
      menuHost.add(option.optionText);       
      
      _this.options[option.key] = option; // stash the option in the lookup list for later retrieval in click handlers.

      // pay attention Bond - if this menu level has a sub-level then we call into this function again.  
      if (option.options){
        
        var optionGroup = addHost(option, menuHost, level + 1, i)  // params 3 & 4 are menu depth and popout depth for positioning the rects. 

        // make an onclick listener to show the sub-options
        option.callback = function(e){
          optionGroup.visible(true);
          layer.draw();
        }        
      }
    }
    return menuHost; // return the konva group 
  } 

  // so - now we can call out addHost function for the top level of the menu and it will recurse as needed down the sub-options.
  var mainGroup = addHost(menuData, this.menuGroup, 0, 0);

  // lets be nice and make a show() method that takes a position x,y too.
  this.show = function(location){
    location.x = location.x - 10;  // little offset to get the group under the mouse
    location.y = location.y - 10;
    
    mainGroup.position(location);
    mainGroup.show(); // notice we do not draw the layer here - leave that to the caller to avoid too much redraw.
  }

  // and if we have a show we better have a hide.
  this.hide = function(){
    mainGroup.hide();
  }
  
  // and a top-level group listener for mouse-out to hide the menu. You might want to put a timer on this [Homework #3]
  mainGroup.on('mouseleave', function(){
    this.hide();
    layer.draw();
  })
  
   
  // end of the menu class object.
  return this;
}


// ok - now we can get our menu data turned into a menu
var theMenu = new menu(menuData);
layer.add(theMenu.menuGroup); // add the returned canvas group to the layer
layer.draw();  // and never forget to draw the layer when it is time!

//
// now we can add some arbitrary callbacks to some of the options.
//
// make a trivial function to pop a message when we click option 1
var helloFunc = function(){
  alert('hello')
}
// make this the callback for opt1 - you can move this inside the menu class object as a setCallback(name, function()) method if you prefer [homework #2] 
theMenu.options['opt1'].callback = helloFunc;

// put a function on sub2 just to show it works.
theMenu.options['opt2-2'].callback = function(){ alert('click on sub-2') };

// and the original reason for this - make it a context menu on a shape.
circle.on('click', function(e){
  theMenu.show({x: e.evt.offsetX, y: e.evt.offsetY});
    layer.draw(); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id='container1' style="width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I'm late but I would use [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), theres a example about it on the react-konva page: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/react/DOM_Portal.html

I forked your sandbox with how this would be done: https://codesandbox.io/s/km0n1x8367

Comment: what would be the best approach to hide the context menu when clicking or taping outside the context menu?